# preventDefault(); override

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've been doing an implementation of this parallax scrolling tutorial:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/

Rather than going with the four-slide set-up in the tutorial, I've gone with a two-slide thing.

I have links on the second slide that need to lead to inside pages, but I'm having a problem with the links even triggering. The culprit comes down to these bits of functions in the implementation:

```
 //When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    links.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
    });
    //When the user clicks on the button, get the get the data-slide attribute value of the button and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
    button.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
    });
```

I've tried commenting out and deleting the `e.preventDefault();` but that doesn't work, and eliminating both functions allows my links to work, but not the parallax scrolling navigation.

My jQuery/JS skills are really negligible, and I'm not able to figure out how to make both the parallax nav and my own links in the second slide work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "My jquery/JS skills are really negligible" - Generally I strongly suggest starting your coding journey by _learning the language_, learn JS, then the DOM API (there are great resources for that! check the tag wikis) and only then useful libraries like jQuery. That way you'd actually know how your code works and what it really does rather than trying out code from internet tutorials and hacking around it.

Comment: Looks to me like the problem isn't with `preventDefault`, or even any of that _function_, but rather the object `links` for which you're using _click_ (which we don't see constructed in the pasted code). Try limiting it to just the slide-scrolling links and not every link.

Comment: @PaulS. Sadly, renaming the object and its corresponding variable (`var slidelinks = $('.nav').find('li');`) didn't do the trick. In any case, I've got the mark-up for the whole page here: http://jsfiddle.net/P7NJ9/